# Using one app setting variable definition in another app setting variable

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files, config

Is there a way to use one app setting variable definition in another app setting variable?

This is an example, right now I have:

```
<add key="P4RootDirectory" value="d:\p4\" />
<add key="P4LocalBranchSyncDirectory" value="d:\p4\sw\matt\" />
```

Ideally, I would like to have something like this

```
<add key="P4RootDirectory" value="d:\p4\" />
<add key="P4LocalBranchSyncDirectory" value="%P4RootDirectory%sw\matt\" />
```

Is this not possible? Would I have to do this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this in code. If you use a DI injection framework that would be a great place to setup and automatically do the replace before injecting the final string into some constructor for example.